# MapStruct map fields to target only when target's fields are null

Tags: java, mapstruct

I am trying to map this object

```
public class Source {
  private String value1;
  private String value2;
  private String value3;
}
```

Into this object

```
public class Target {
  private String targetValue1;
  private String targetValue2;
  private String targetValue3;
}
```

This is the Mapper definition.

```
@Mapper
public interface SourceMapper {
  void toTarget(Source source, @MappingTarget Target target);
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is only map fields in `source` into `target` only when the fields in `target` are `null`. For example, `source.value1` only maps to `target.targetValue1` when `target.targetValue1` is `null`. If it is not `null`, the mapping for that field is ignored.

Is it possible with MapStruct without having to write custom code?

**Edit**
I changed the field names of `Target` to make it clear that the names of the `Target` may/may not match the names of the fields in `Source`.

Comment: Why do you want to map fields in source to target.

Comment: @RamPrakash `source` and `target` are just example classes but I do need to write a conversion from a class to another class.

Comment: If you are converting Source Object to target Object. You use copy utils from spring

Comment: Interesting, I don't know about it. Is that `org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils`? I looked at the `copyProperties` method in that class. It requires that the properties in both the `source` and `target` must match. This is not the case for me even though my example seems to imply that. I updated my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that can be done with mapstruct. If you still want to use mapstruct, you can ignore the target variables that could be *null* with `@Mapping (target =" propName ", ignore = true)` and decide yourself with a `@AfterMapping` method when you set your target variables.

Comment: By using `@AfterMapping`, I have to manually perform the check and map anyway. This defeats the purpose of using MapStruct. It is unfortunate that MapStruct does not support this. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by doing the following trick:
first, you need to know that you can control the mapping behavior on 'source' nulls fields
using `Mapping.nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy()`
So the following should do the work:

```
Target target = new Target(); // the actual target, first grade values
Source source = new Source(); // the actual source, secund grade values
Target result = new Target(); // the result
SourceMapper.toTarget(source, result); // now you have secund grade value
SourceMapper.toTarget(target, result); /* now you overide the secund grade value only 
if the first grade isn't null */


@Mapper
public interface SourceMapper {
@Mapping(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE)
void toTarget(Target source, @MappingTarget Target target);

void toTarget(Source source, @MappingTarget Target target);
}
```