# Mapstruct - ingore mapping when target is null

Tags: java, mapstruct

Consider the below codes, if `engine` is null, I don't want to map it. How can I do it?

```java
@Mapper
public interface CarMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "engine", source = "device")
    void updateCarFromDto(CarDto carDto, @MappingTarget Car car);
}
```

Comment: @Reilas, your suggested question is `when source is null` and my question is `when target is null`

Comment: Try this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59740439/mapstruct-map-fields-to-target-only-when-targets-fields-are-null).  They're referring to the `NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy` enum; another value possibly?

Comment: @Reilas, from your suggested question: What I am trying to achieve is only `map fields in source into target only when the fields in target are null`. I want to ignore instead.

Comment: Also `NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy` only control source but not target.

Comment: Alright, so there is a similar [question](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1443) on GitHub, for setting values only when the fields in target are null.

Comment: @Reilas, Thanks. so there is no native support from MapStruct and I leave my answer for reference.

Comment: Which version of used Mapstruct?

Comment: @fatih 1.5.5.Final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `ignore` and `@AfterMapping`.

```java
@Mapper
public interface CarMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "engine", ignore = "true")
    void updateCarFromDto(CarDto carDto, @MappingTarget Car car);

    @AfterMapping
    default void update(CarDto carDto, @MappingTarget Car car) {
        if(car == null || carDto == null) {
            return;
        }

        if(car.getEngine != null)
            car.setEngine(carDto.getDevice);
            
    }
}
```